# QtMultimedia on RaspBerry Pi

Tags: video, services, qt

I've been trying to get [QtMultimedia](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediaoverview.html) working on Raspberry Pi for a few weeks now, cross-compiling using the BakeQtPi script, yet the QtMultimedia plugin never seems to find an appropriate service to output video through a MediaPlayer element, which has got me finding myself at my wits end.

Is there anyone out there who has gotten the Qt videoplayer working on QtOnPi, and would be so kind to provide *any* form of helpful documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried QT development without success, I will come back to the issue when I get time

Answer (score 2):

If you want I wrote a GPL-licensed QtMultimedia backend providing hw acceleration to QML elements like MediaPlayer and VideoOutput. Look here: https://bugfreeblog.duckdns.org/2013/04/hardware-accelerated-qtmultimedia.html.

Answer (score 0):

### Latest Raspbian or Arch Linux, GST 1.x & gst-mmal

You can get clean and fully hardware accelerated video easily on the Raspberry without using hackish build methods or hacked binary-only images/tgz from the internets (some people may even be scared if you get malware inside of them), it's easier even than obscure Yocto overlays. **Just use latest Raspbian**.

There is GStreamer 1.x on latest Raspbian, Qt has transparent GST 1.0 support, but you will need MMAL, [read about it here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/events/gstreamer-conference/2016/John%20Sadler%20-%20Smooth%20video%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi%20with%20gst-mmal%20(Lightning%20Talk).pdf). Then get it from [Github's gst-mmal](https://github.com/youviewtv/gst-mmal).

- Get Gstreamer 1.x (apt)
- Get gst-mmal, you'll have to build it
- Test with `gst-play-1.0`
- Have fun with fully GL accelerated video on Qt & Qt Quick

Maybe by the time you read this it's even on a ppa.