# Is it possible to install Qt5 on Ubuntu MATE or Raspbian with Raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, video, ubuntu, qt

First of all, I'm not sure if I should be asking this here, or on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). But, here will be my first shot, if it's not the right place, just tell me and I'll move the question elsewhere.

Ok, now the the problem itself.

I've developed a Qt5 app, and I'd like to see it running on the pi2. First of all I noticed that Ubuntu MATE 15.04 comes with Qt 4.8 by default, and it have qt5-base and qmake5 on it's apt-get repository. But when I tried to use it, I've ran into some dependency problems, and the qt5 ended up not beign installed at all.

I've found [this tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) to compile qt5 from scratch on rasp1 with raspbian, and [this one](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) to do the same on rasp2, but that can take a long while, and lots of things can go wrong, so if it's possible to just do an apt-get it'll be A LOT easier for me (and anyone else who might step into this same problem).

And I would also want to know if after it's compiled, if my program will be able to play hardware accelerated videos using [`QMediaPlayer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html).

P.S.: Yes, I've bought the licenses to decode AVC-1 and MPEG in the hardware.

Edit: I've found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/vlc-hardware-acceleration) talking about an Hardware accelerated VLC, it's slightly related to my problem, I guess.

Edit 2: Which packages would be enough to compile a Qt project that needs only the QtCore/QtBase and QtMultimedia?

Edit 3: I've followed the instructions on the answers and comments, using the Raspbian Jessie repository to install qt5. I've ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediawidgets5
```

And the package manager installed lots of dependencies along.

After that, I've tried to run `qtconfig` but I got this error:

```
qtconfig: could not exec '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qtconfig': No such file or directory
```

And after that, I tried to run `qmake` on my project, and I got:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimediawidgets multimedia
```

Well, I feel a little lost here...

Edit 4: I've also found [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7519/qtmultimedia-on-raspberry-pi?rq=1) here. I guess this guy is having a similar problem.

Edit 5: Yupp, I'm not the only one with this problem. As you can see [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60410-qtmultimedia-video-hardware-acceleartion-on-raspberry-pi).

Answer (score 2):

Raspbian jessie appears to have qt5 in the repository. If you're still on Wheezy, you can upgrade it through [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-linux-system-from-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release).

```
$ cat /etc/os-release  
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

A trimmed apt-cache search

```
$ apt-cache search qt5
...
libqt5gui5 - Qt 5 GUI module
libqt5help5 - Qt 5 help module
libqt5keychain0 - Qt API to store passwords (QT5 version)
libqt5multimedia5 - Qt 5 Multimedia module
libqt5multimedia5-plugins - Qt 5 Multimedia module plugins
libqt5multimediaquick-p5 - Qt 5 Multimedia Quick module
libqt5multimediawidgets5 - Qt 5 Multimedia Widgets module
libqt5network5 - Qt 5 network module
libqt5nfc5 - Qt Connectivity NFC module
libqt5opengl5 - Qt 5 OpenGL module
libqt5opengl5-dev - Qt 5 OpenGL library development files
libqt5positioning5 - Qt Positioning module
libqt5positioning5-plugins - Qt Positioning module - position plugins
libqt5printsupport5 - Qt 5 print support module
libqt5qml5 - Qt 5 QML module
libqt5quick5 - Qt 5 Quick library
libqt5quickparticles5 - Qt 5 Quick particules module
libqt5quicktest5 - Qt 5 Quick Test library
libqt5quickwidgets5 - Qt 5 Quick Widgets library
libqt5scintilla2-11 - Qt5 port of the Scintilla source code editing widget
libqt5scintilla2-11-dbg - Qt5 port of the Scintilla source code editing widget (debug)
libqt5scintilla2-designer - Qt5 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2
libqt5scintilla2-designer-dbg - Qt5 Designer plugin for QScintilla 2 (debug)
libqt5scintilla2-dev - Scintilla source code editing widget for Qt5, development files
libqt5scintilla2-l10n - Scintilla source code editing widget for Qt5, translation files
libqt5script5 - Qt 5 script module
libqt5scripttools5 - Qt 5 script tools module
libqt5sensors5 - Qt Sensors module
libqt5sensors5-dev - Qt 5 Sensors development files
libqt5serialport5 - Qt 5 serial port support
libqt5serialport5-dev - Qt 5 serial port development files
libqt5sql5 - Qt 5 SQL module
libqt5sql5-mysql - Qt 5 MySQL database driver
libqt5sql5-odbc - Qt 5 ODBC database driver
libqt5sql5-psql - Qt 5 PostgreSQL database driver
libqt5sql5-sqlite - Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
libqt5sql5-tds - Qt 5 FreeTDS database driver
libqt5svg5 - Qt 5 SVG module
libqt5svg5-dev - Qt 5 SVG module development files
libqt5svg5-private-dev - Qt 5 SVG module private development files
libqt5test5 - Qt 5 test module
libqt5webkit5 - Web content engine library for Qt
libqt5webkit5-dev - Web content engine library for Qt - development files
libqt5websockets5 - Qt 5 Web Sockets module
libqt5websockets5-dev - Qt 5 Web Sockets module - development files
libqt5widgets5 - Qt 5 widgets module
libqt5x11extras5 - Qt 5 X11 extras
libqt5x11extras5-dev - Qt 5 X11 extras development files
libqt5xml5 - Qt 5 XML module
libqt5xmlpatterns5 - Qt 5 XML patterns module
libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev - Qt 5 XML patterns development files
libqt5xmlpatterns5-private-dev - Qt 5 XML patterns private development files
...
```

Comment: Is this the latest release? If it's not, where can I get it?

Comment: I'm not sure if Raspbian defaults to wheezy or jessie. I just downloaded the latest version (wheezy at the time) and changed wheezy to jessie in the source lists.  Search for update to jessie.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26041/how-can-i-access-raspbian-jessie-packages-from-wheezy

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try to use the qt5 from Jessie without upgrading. If I'm unsuccessful, I'll try to upgrade it.

Comment: It seems to have installed, I can find the qmake but... some stuff are not working that well. Like qtconfig, it throws an error like: `qtconfig: could not exec '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qtconfig': No such file or directory` and even if I've installed `libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins`, when I try to run qmake on my project I get: `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimediawidgets multimedia`